# How to custom title of weekday of Material-ui DateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I spend almost half day but can't not found any solution to customize the title of week day of Material-ui DateRangePicker. Instead of "S", "M",..., I want to show the title as I expected.
Already tried to custom the dateAdapter but this not helps.
I see that Material-ui has component called MuiPickersUtilsProvider which I can customize the day title as I want but this component not support date-range picker.
I would highly appreciate any advices. Here is my code so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MobileDateRangePicker from '@mui/lab/MobileDateRangePicker';

export class CustomDateFns extends AdapterDateFns {
  getWeekdays() {
    return ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'GG'];
  }
}

export default function ResponsiveDateRangePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([null, null]);
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={CustomDateFns}>
      <MobileDateRangePicker
        inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
        startText="Start date"
        endText="End date"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        clearable={!!value[0] && !!value[1] ? true : false}
        clearText="Reset"
        cancelText=""
        okText="Confirm"
        toolbarTitle=""
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <TextField {...startProps} />
            <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
            <TextField {...endProps} />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Here is what current it shows:

[image]

What I expect is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found until now is manipulating the DOM, then set innerHTML. But I don't think this is a good way because we can't control DOM as this is generated by library, not by me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dayOfWeekFormatter` property to format day-of-week labels.

If you need more detailed information and examples, you can refer to the
[Documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/adapters-locale/#custom-day-of-week-format) or the discussion on GitHub: [Day of Week Formatting in MUI X Date Pickers](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4605).